# Change value in pandas series based on hour of the day using df.apply and if statement

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, apply, series

I have large df with datettime index with hourly time step and precipitation values in several columns. My precipitation valuesare a cumulative total during the day (from 1:00 am to 0:00 am of the next day) and are reset after every day, example:

```
datetime                      S1                                                                        
2000-01-01 00:00:00          4.5  ...  
2000-01-01 01:00:00            0  ...  
2000-01-01 02:00:00            0  ...  
2000-01-01 03:00:00            0  ...  
2000-01-01 04:00:00            0
2000-01-01 05:00:00            0
2000-01-01 06:00:00            0
2000-01-01 07:00:00            0
2000-01-01 08:00:00            0
2000-01-01 09:00:00            0
2000-01-01 10:00:00            0
2000-01-01 11:00:00          6.5
2000-01-01 12:00:00          7.5
2000-01-01 13:00:00          8.7
2000-01-01 14:00:00          8.7
...
2000-01-01 22:00:00          8.7
2000-01-01 23:00:00          8.7
2000-01-02 00:00:00          8.7
2000-01-02 01:00:00            0
```

I am trying to go from this to the actual hourly values, so the value for 1:00 am for every day is fine and then I want to substract the value from the timestep before.
Can I somehow use if statement inside of df.apply?
I thought of smth like:

```
df_copy = df.copy()
df = df.apply(lambda x: if df.hour !=1: era5_T[x]=era5_T[x]-era5_T_copy[x-1])
```

But this is not working since I'm not calling a function? I could work with a for loop but that doesn't seem like the most efficient way as I'm working with a big dataset.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `numpy.where` and `pd.Series.shift` to acheive the result

```py
import numpy as np
df['hourly_S1'] = np.where(df.hour ==1, df.S1, df.S1-df.S1.shift())
```

Comment: I used your solution with a loop over all columns (there are more than S1). Works fine, thank you!